# How to get product variation price in woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In the hook woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item I want to change the item metas in the checkout page for more than one quantity and now I need the variation price to calculate this.

```
function wpler_add_quantities_to_order_items($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');
    //$product = $values['data']; // Variation Product-Object
    //$product = $item->get_product();
    $product = wc_get_product($item->get_variation_id());
    $price1 = $product->get_rpice(); //$product->get_variation_regular_price('min');
    $price2 = $product->get_sale_price(); //$product->get_variation_sale_price('min');
    $r = $order->get_billing_postcode();

    $rabatt = !empty($r)&&is_numeric($r)&&$r>0 ? doubleval($r) : 0;
    $ep1 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity']), $rabatt);
    $ep2 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity10']), $rabatt);
    $ep3 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity20']), $rabatt);
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis f&uuml;r {$values['quantity']} St&uuml;ck", money_format('%.2n', $ep1));
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis f&uuml;r {$values['quantity10']} St&uuml;ck", money_format('%.2n', $ep2));
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis f&uuml;r {$values['quantity20']} St&uuml;ck", money_format('%.2n', $ep3));
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'wpler_add_quantities_to_order_items', 10, 4);
```

On the regular price are the normal price for the first piece. On sale price are the price for the rest of quantity pieces.

Example: 
variation-article, regular price = 5.00, sale price = 1.00

order are 50 x variation-article

So, I'm calculate `((49 x 1)+5) = 54.00`

But also we want show different quantity suggestions with 500 and 5000 quantities, which are should display in the checkout.

My problem on the function above is that i need the regular and sale price of the variation product. How can i get this?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found the solution:

In the object $item i found this:

`$item->legacy_values['variation_id']`

which gives me the ID. Also in `$item->legacy_values[]` array i have the both prices, which i take now:

```
function wpler_add_quantities_to_order_items($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');
    $price1 = doubleval($item->legacy_values['price1']);
    $price2 = doubleval($item->legacy_values['price2']);
    $r = $order->get_billing_postcode();

    $rabatt = !empty($r)&&is_numeric($r)&&$r>0 ? doubleval($r) : 0;
    $ep1 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity']), $rabatt);
    $ep2 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity10']), $rabatt);
    $ep3 = calcPrices($price1, $price2, intval($values['quantity20']), $rabatt);
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis für {$values['quantity']} Stück", money_format('%.2n', $ep1));
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis für {$values['quantity10']} Stück", money_format('%.2n', $ep2));
    $item->add_meta_data("Preis für {$values['quantity20']} Stück", money_format('%.2n', $ep3));
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'wpler_add_quantities_to_order_items', 10, 4);
```